# How to use StringByAppendingFormat in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift

Code:

```
var postString: NSString = NSString .stringByAppendingFormat("userName=\(userName) & password = \(Password)")
```

Why I am getting error as:

```
(NSString, CVarArgType...) -> NSString' is not convertible to NSString.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringByAppendingFormat:` is an instance method on `NSString`, not a class method. Therefore, you can't call it with `NSString.stringByAppendingFormat(...)`, you have to call it on an exiting string:

```
var someExistingString = "..."
var postString = someExistingString.stringByAppendingFormat("userName = %@ & password = %@", userName, password)
```

That being said, you don't need to use `stringByAppendingFormat` if you're just constructing a new string from scratch, you can use Swift's [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_430) directly:

```
var postString = "userName = \(userName) & password = \(password)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're trying to call an instance method `stringByAppendingFormat` on a the class `NSString`. Here's an example that compiles:

```
var userName = "Dave"
var Password = "password"

var select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE "

var postString: NSString = select.stringByAppendingFormat("userName=\(userName) & password = \(Password)")
```

*Note*: You never want to do something like this because of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).